# Loopback JS model connetion with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I want to use LoopbackJS framework to write some quick APIs.

The thing is that I want to connect my model with the mongodb loopback connector to do some simple find queries.

These are my files:

**/server/model-config.js**

```
"transaction": {
    "dataSource": "mongo",
    "public": true
}
```

**/server/datasources.json**

```
"mongo": {
    "name": "mongo",
    "connector": "mongodb"
}
```

**/common/models/transaction.js**

```
module.exports = function(Transaction) {

    Transaction.find({}, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

};
```

The following is failing with this error:

**Error: Cannot call transaction.find(). The find method has not been setup. The PersistedModel has not been correctly attached to a DataSource!**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your code should be inside a hook ( operation, remote or connector ).
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Adding+logic+to+models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment that this code is executed

```
Transaction.find({}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The framework is not prepared to do things yet. You should register a hook callback in order to execute your business logic.

A example would be:

```
Transaction.observe('before save', function doStuf(ctx, next) {
   Transaction.find({}, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        next();// be sure to call the callback function
   });
}
```

Other hooks are defined in this link:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Adding+logic+to+models